# ¿Cómo obtengo un request de un API Rest en mi HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, web

Lo que no me sale es cómo capturar la respuesta del request que me da la API de lo solicitado al hacer click en el enlace y poder volcarlo en un div de pagina principal en mi HTML,yo hice esto hasta ahora pero el enlace me envia a otra pestaña y no me manda el contenido en la misma pagina HTML. y si le anulo el comportamiento por defecto no me muestra la respuesta del request a la API

```
function api1(){

  $.ajax({
     url: 'https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/',
     type :"GET",
  })

  .done (function(data) {
     $('#respuesta').html(data);
  })   

  .fail(function(data) {
     alert('error')
  })

  .always(function(data) {
     alert('complete')
  })
}

<article>
   <a id="en1" onclick=api1() href="https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/">Link API 1
   </a>
</article>

<div id="seccion2" class="seccion2">

  <div id="cajita1" class="cajita1">

  </div>

  <div id="cajita2" class="cajita2">
                
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes **entrecomillar** la función en el evento **onclick** y debes quitar el contenido del **href** para que no haga el salto de este modo:

```
<a id="en1" onclick="api1()" href="#">Link API 1</a>
```

Tambien debes agregar un elemento con el id **respuesta** para mostrar el contenido obtenido.

```
<img id="respuesta" src="" style="width:250px;">
```

Y piensa que, en este caso, jquery interpreta la respuesta **data** como un objeto, por lo tanto debes tratarlo como tal (y no como **html**).  He cambiado esa línea por esta:

```
     $('#respuesta').attr('src',data.image_link);
```

Tal como aclaras en el comentario de esta respuesta, lo que tambien quieres es mostrar todas las propiedades en un div tal cual, por lo tanto puedes convertir el objeto data mediante el uso del método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), que eso provocará la conversión del objeto **data** a **string** y podrás imprimirlo con el método `.html(data)` de jquery.

Es decir, puedes crearte otro elemento, en este caso un div, con otro id único, por ejemplo, respuestaHtml, y pasarle el string con esto:

```
$('#respuestaHtml').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Para ver todas las propiedades del objeto **data** puedes hacer un `console.log(data)` y te las mostrará de este modo en la consola:

```
{
  active_time: "Diurnal",
  animal_type: "Fish",
  diet: "Plankton",
  geo_range: "Africa",
  habitat: "Lakes",
  id: 22,
  image_link: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Copadichromis_azureus.jpg",
  latin_name: "Copadichromis azureus",
  length_max: "0.55",
  length_min: "0.42",
  lifespan: "8",
  name: "Azureus Cichlid",
  weight_max: "0.75",
  weight_min: "0.5"
}
```

Aquí un snippet funcional que puedes ejecutar para ver su funcionamiento:

```js
function api1(){

  $.ajax({
     url: 'https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/',
     type :"GET"
  })

  .done (function(data) {
     $('#respuesta').attr('src',data.image_link);
     $('#respuestaHtml').html(JSON.stringify(data));
  })   

  .fail(function(data) {
     alert('error')
  })

  .always(function(data) {
     alert('complete')
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
   <a id="en1" onclick="api1()" href="#">Link API 1</a>
</article>

<img id="respuesta" src="" style="width:250px;">
<div id="respuestaHtml"></div>
```

Comment: antes que nada gracias por la respuesta! y  eso que me comentas no lo sabia! y otra duda el data que yo envio al console.log se puede mostrar al lado de la imagen o debajo en este ejemplo que me pasaste?? porque el ejercicio me pide mostrar en una caja  todas esas propiedades del objeto al hacer click en el link sin que se vaya a otra pestaña, asi como se ve la imagen pero con todas las propiedades. Se puede hacer de alguna manera? eso aun no lo consigo

Comment: @pablo vale, al final te lo he puesto todo junto, imagen y string... actualiza la página y relee mi respuesta para ver si con eso ya lo tienes como necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Bien, te falta una cosas:

Dónde está la ID *respuesta* en tu HTML ?

Para mostrar en el DOM, elige una ID que este en el DOM: en este caso `cajita1`.

Esto es un ejemplo funcional:

(**EDITADO**)

```js
// Propio de la librería jQuery
$(function() {
 
 //Tu función
 function api1() {

  $.ajax({
   
 url: 'https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/',
 type :"GET",
   
  }).done (function(data) {
   
 $('.cajita1').html(data);
   
  }).fail(function(data) {
   
 alert('error')
   
  }).always(function(data) {
   
 alert('complete')
   
  });
 
 };
 
});
```

```html
<article>
   <a id="en1" onclick=api1() href="https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/">Link API 1
   </a>
</article>

  <div id="seccion2" class="seccion2"> 
   
   <div id="cajita1" class="cajita1"></div>
   
   <div id="cajita2" class="cajita2"></div> 
   
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No olvides marcar con ✓ ésta respuesta si te ayudo. Esto es para que sirva a otros que necesiten lo mismo.

Comment: Lo siento, no funciona bien esta solución aunque lo parezca, pues si la ejecutas verás que lo que hace es seguir el href solamente, por eso me veo obligado a votarla negativamente.

Comment: Ok @masterguru. Simplemente no probé el codigo. Puede que eliminé mi respuesta porque está de más

Comment: Como quieras, aunque quizas se te ocurra como arreglarla y responder mejor que las otras respuestas, eso ya es cosa tuya. Lo único que indicaba es que tal como está no es útil y de ahí mi voto, lo siento.

Comment: Yo no veo voto negativo.

Comment: no lo ves porque ya tenias uno de positivo y el mio lo ha contrarestado (desde luego hay gente que le encanta votar positivamente sin comprobar si funcionan las respuestas, por muy bien redactadas que esten)